# divide list of items to two columns

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

imagine if i have an array of [1,2,3,4] and I need to be two columns as flexbox will divide like that :
1:2
3:4
I need like that for responsive reseasons
1:3
2:4

here the code :

```
<ul className="w-full md:p-10 flex justify-between flex-wrap md:flex-row flex-col  md:relative static">
                      {list.items.map((item, index)=> (
                        <div className='w-1/2'>
                          <li key={index} className="hover:md:bg-light py-3 md:px-6" >
                             <a href={t(item.url)}>
                                <h3 className="md:font-semibold font-normal text-base md:text-primary text-lightDarkGrey mb-2">{t(item.title)}</h3>
                                <p className='font-normal text-xs text-black hidden md:block md:w-3/5 w-full opacity-50'>{t(item.desc)}</p>
                              </a>
                          </li>
                          </div>
                      ))
                    }
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually define your styles accordingly using css-grid component:

```
ul {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 9.879rem); // you can put whatever width you want for your columns 
   }

li {align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;}
```